# Confused about Laravel "sometimes" validation works

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I'm really confused about why this is happening? I had successfully added a record then when I tried to update the record It says that the field is required even I passing it already. Then when I tried to add "sometimes" on the validation. Now, it works. Why? Please enlighten me. Thank you!

[my Test Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4Y41.png)

[This was the result when I tried to remove "sometimes"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlS8I.png)

Comment: Please don't use pictures for code, use formatted text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sometimes` is when you **sometimes** include the field.

Let's see an example of validation when creating a user:-

```
$validation = [
 "name" => "required|string|",
 "email" => "required|email",
 "hobbies" => "sometimes|array"
];
```

**Sample payloads**

```
{
 name: "Bob",
 email: "bob@gmail.com"
}
// this will pass
```

```
{
 name: "Bob",
 email: "bob@gmail.com",
 hobbies: ["fishing", "swimming"]
}
// this would also pass
```

```
{
 name: "Bob",
 email: "bob@gmail.com",
 hobbies: "swimming"
}
// this would fail since it doesn't match "array" validation
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the doc `sometimes` is used for :

> Validating When Present In some situations, you may wish to run
>   validation checks against a field only if that field is present in the
>   input array. To quickly accomplish this, add the sometimes rule to
>   your rule list:
>
> ```
> $v = Validator::make($data, [
>     'email' => 'sometimes|required|email', ]);
> ```

Therefore since the request is not containing the expected fields, the validation is successful

Comment: Without seeing the validation logic, that's the best I can provide

Answer (score 1):

Adding `sometimes` effectively disables the `required` rule and allows the client to simply not pass that field into the input.

In your case, the validator is probably not receiving the correct data from input. Because If it did, the `required` rule would act correctly.

Please post the code of your validator to be able to debug the problem.